# Verification of proof of two continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $b$ be a real number. Define the functions $f_b,f_g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$

$f_b = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{$x\cdot cos(\frac{1}{x})$,} &\text{if $x\in\mathbb{R}$\ $\{0\}$}\\
       \text{$b$,} &\text{if $x=0$}\\
     \end{cases}$

$g_b = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{$1$,} &\text{if $x>0$}\\
       \text{$b$,} &\text{if $x=0$}\\
       \text{$-1$,} &\text{if $x<0$}\\
     \end{cases}$

(a) Find a real number $b$, such that the function $f_b$ is continuous and argue why $f_b$ is continuous with the real number

(b) Does any other options for $b$ exists in question (a)? (If there are no more real numbers that make $f_b$ continuous, explain why)

(c) Does a real number $b$ exists, such that $g_b$ is continuous? If no; explain why.

---

(a) For $f_b(x)$ if $b=0$ then $f_b(x)$ to be continuous as the limit tends 0. We have $$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f_b(x)=\lim_{x \to 0^-} x\cdot cos(\frac{1}{x})=0$$
and $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f_b(x)=\lim_{x \to 0^+} x\cdot cos(\frac{1}{x})=0$$
and of course $$f_b(0)=0$$

Which implies that $f_b(x)$ is continuous at 0, and $f_b(x)$ is also continuous in all other non-zero points as it is a product of two continuous functions.

(b) There are no other value of $b$ such that $f_b(x)$ is still continuous. It follows from the argument in (a).

(c) In $g_b$ we have $$\lim_{x \to 0^-} g_b(x)=-1$$
and $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} g_b(x)=1$$

Therefore $g_b$ is discontinuous at $x=0$ as $$\lim_{x \to 0^-} g_b(x)\neq\lim_{x \to 0^+} g_b(x)$$ and therefore no $b$ exists such that $g_b$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems correct, but the answer is only acceptable if you've reached a level where you are allowed to use the limit argument.

If you're restricted to $\delta-\epsilon$ arguments (together with the fact that composition and arithmetic operations on continuous function yields continuous result) you use the fact that $|f_b(x)|<x$ if $x\ne 0$ which means that if $b\ne 0$ there exists an $\epsilon = |b|/2$ such that for every $\delta > 0$ there exists an $|x|<\delta$ such that $|f_b(x)-b|\ge \epsilon$ which means that it's not continuous then. On the other hand if $b=0$ you have that if $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta =\epsilon$ then for any $|x|<\delta$ you have that $|f_b(x)|\le |x|<\delta=\epsilon$. This answers the a and b questions.

For the last you use a similar reasoning by assuming that if $b\ne 1$ then $g_b$ is not continuous and if $b\ne -1$ it's not continuous either. Then you observe that $b\ne 1$ or $b\ne -1$ so it's certainly not continuous.